# Getting error: expression not assignable

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I can't find any answers on why it's giving me an error: `expression is not assignable` on lines 11 and 20.

This is a simple code for creating a random array and then sort it using a subroutine. I'm still learning C and couldn't find a solution with any research.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int myArray[100];
int* ptr = myArray;
int i;
int n = sizeof(myArray);
int SortedArray[100];

int MakeRandArray(ptr, i)
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        (ptr + i) = rand()
    }
}

int SortArray(ptr)
{
    int a;
    int j = (i + 1);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ((ptr + i) > (ptr + j)) {
            (ptr + i) = (ptr + j)
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    MakeRandArray(*ptr, i);
    SortArray(*ptr);
}
```

Comment: `*(ptr+1)` to dereference a calculated pointer. But there is much more to be fixed in your code.

Comment: Not speaking of the lack of the type of `ptr` in function definition...

Comment: A semicolon wouldn't hurt too.

Comment: `int n = sizeof(myArray);` --> `int n = sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(*myArray);`

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/JjIePT)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Giving good answers is very much typical for you, doing so via an external link in a comment not so. Spotting your other comment earlier would have saved me an awkward detour on the other hand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version with the errors avoided and `-Wall`warnings, too.
I did not change things which are against good coding practice. Take some time later to learn about those, too. Read the comments on your question and on this answer for doing that.
As an encore I got your sorting working (in a very blind, inefficient way) and added a printer, for demonstration purposes. I use array size 10 instead of 100, for convenience. It seems that you intend to keep the orignal array and create a sorted version, I left that for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    int myArray[10];
    int *ptr = myArray;
    // int i; Do not use globals for counters inside functions.

    // it would be better to give the size of arrays as an explicit
    // parameter to functions, instead of using a global variable
    // (keeping this only for minimised differences to your code)
    int n = sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(int);

void MakeRandArray(int *ptr)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *(ptr + i) = rand();
    }
}

void PrintArray(int *ptr)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%8d\n", *(ptr + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void SortArray(int *ptr)
{
    // this is far off even the simplest sorting algorithms
    // it is worth reading up on one (e.g. the quite simple bubble sort),
    // then enjoy optimising this (my) totally blind method here;
    // note that I sort within the original array,
    // you seem to intend to keep unsorted in addition to sorted
    int i;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {   int help;
            if (*(ptr+i) > *(ptr + i + 1))
            {
                help = *(ptr+i);
                *(ptr + i) = *(ptr + i + 1);
                *(ptr + i + 1)=help;
            }
        }
    }
}    

int main(void)
{
    MakeRandArray(ptr);
    PrintArray(ptr);
    SortArray(ptr);
    PrintArray(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
      41
   18467
    6334
   26500
   19169
   15724
   11478
   29358
   26962
   24464

      41
    6334
   11478
   15724
   18467
   19169
   24464
   26500
   26962
   29358
```

Comment: Too many global variables — far too many global variables.  Also, because you have `int n = sizeof(myArray);`, you are accessing out of bounds.  Using the global variable `i` in the sort code is a bit nasty.  Use `*(ptr + idx)` instead of `ptr[idx]` is not great.

Comment: Fixed the out of bound (noticed myself, but thanks). Kept the code as close to OPs version as possible.

Comment: The OP's code is really not good enough to warrant keeping your code close to it.  Where did the `0` come from, and where did the `29358` go to?

Comment: Not for making good code, but for making easy to learn about the reason for the question, from the minimised differences.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Fixed the wrong 0/missing max. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: While you use global `i`, I'm not prepared to up-vote.  That is egregiously wrong — I can't think of a circumstance where it would be a good idea to have that variable.  Fix that in all the functions, and  I'll be OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145919/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: Removed the global loop counter, agreeing with @JonathanLeffler that it is worth introducing a few more differences. Thanks, Jonathan, for otherwise understanding my intention to help by making minimal changes.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't dereferencing the pointer properly.

At line 11:

```
ptr[i] = rand();
```

At line 20:

```
if (ptr[i] > ptr[j]){
    ptr[i] = ptr[j];
}
```

Alternatively you can specify `*(ptr + i)` to get the value at `ptr[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using old-style (pre-standard, K&R style) function definitions.  You should be using the faintly modern C90 and later prototype style function definitions.

You wrote:

```
int MakeRandArray(ptr, i)
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        (ptr + i) = rand()
    }
}
```

In this function as shown, the type of `ptr` is `int`, as is the type of `i` — they are implicitly typed to `int` because you didn't specify the type.  (Note that these variables are unrelated to the global variables `ptr` and `i` — they simply hide the global variables.  They do *not* inherit the same type as the global variables.)  You should pass `n` to the function and should not pass `i` to the function.  You should avoid all those global variables.

You immediate compilation error is because you omit the `*` from `*(ptr + i)` and you also omit the `;` at the end of the statement.  You should use `ptr[i]` because it is simpler, easy to type, easier to read, more reliable, and generally more beneficial to everyone than the alternative.

You claim your function returns an `int`; it returns nothing.

Thus, your code for this function should be:

```
void MakeRandArray(int *ptr, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ptr[i] = rand();
}
```

You can put the braces around the body of the loop if you prefer; personally, I don't prefer that.  Defining `i` in the loop like that requires a compiler that handles C99 mode.  If you were really stuck, you could define `int i;` before the loop and remove `int` from the loop control line.  However, you're on a Mac; you are not that stuck.

There are similar issues throughout the code.

```
// Syntactically valid; semantically dubious - it does not sort!
void SortArray(int *ptr, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int j = i + 1;
        if (ptr[i] > ptr[j])
            ptr[i] = ptr[j];
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    MakeRandArray(myArray, 100);
    SortArray(myArray, 100);
}
```

Note that even though it should compile, it won't sort the array.  Of course, you've not shown any printing code, so you can't demonstrate that the array is, or is not, sorted.  You'd need to do that.  You could write a function to check that the array is sorted.

Your sort function will need a second loop inside it, iterating `j`.  You will need to swap elements, not simply overwrite them.

Your definition of `n` is:

```
int n = sizeof(myArray);
```

This probably sets `n` to 400.  If you want the size of an array, you need `int n = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]);` which gives the correct answer in this context.  You should be able to do without that variable, and the global `i`, `ptr`.  You don't use `SortedArray` at all.  The `myArray` could be local to `main()` — which means you need no global variables at all.  Try to avoid global variables; they are often not a good idea.